# How to access two Ids in one css selector

Tags: css

I have div which has three buttons as,

```
<div id="buttons">
    <input id="preview" class="ButtonStyle" type="submit" value="Preview" name="preview">
    <input id="add" class="ButtonStyle" type="submit" value="Save" name="add">
    <input id="Cancel" class="ButtonStyle" type="submit" value="Cancel" name="Cancel">
</div>
```

I set its style. I want that both add and cancel button have their left-margin: 5px; Right now I am doing it in this manner,

```
#outboxmidpg #buttons input[type="submit"]{
    font-weight: bold;
    width: 70px;
}

#outboxmidpg #buttons input[id="Cancel"] {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

#outboxmidpg #buttons input[id="add"] {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

I want to do it in one line. I tried this, but it didn't work and it removes the cancel button margin too.

```
#outboxmidpg #buttons input[id="Cancel"] input[id="add"] {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Is there anyway that I can achieve the style in one line?

Thanks

Answer (score 46, accepted):

```
#buttons input:nth-child(2), #buttons input:nth-child(3){
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

does this work for you ?

or simply:

```
#Cancel, #add{
    margin-left:5px;
}
```

With `,` seperation you start a complete new CSS Selector and combine them.

Comment: Oh that's good. Yup first one is working but why are you asking for this? Is it not common? I used the first one because it's new for me. You are selecting childs. Looking good:) But please tell me which one is better or it's just a matter of style  or preference?  Thanks

Comment: You should stick with the second version, because elder browsers and also new Internet Explorer versions do NOT support nth-child !! I just wanted to know if it works ;-).

Comment: Oh, but why browsers are not supporting nth-child? Do they have any valid reason for it? Asking just for curiosity:)

Comment: I don't konw you should ask that the developers of IE :-D

Answer (score 6):

Best practice to do is:
Just put all the id's/class and separate them by commas (,)
then insert your custom style on its body.

```
#Button_One, #Button_Two {
vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-top:  1px;
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
#outboxmidpg #buttons input[id="Cancel"], #outboxmidpg #buttons input[id="add"] {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate selector by comma (,) in their respective full qualified paths, otherwise it won't work:

```
#outboxmidpg #buttons input[id="Cancel"],
#outboxmidpg #buttons input[id="add"] {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in one line, but it will be two selectors. Try this:

```
#outboxmidpg #buttons input#Cancel, #outboxmidpg #buttons input#add {
    margin-left: 5px;
}
```

Also, try to use `#` when selecting id's, it's the proper way to select them.