# AlloyUI selector for multiple ids

Tags: liferay-aui, alloy-ui

I want to call a function on blur of two elements, but I can only get it to work for a single element.

I used the `A.one()` method to select the elements.

Here is my code:

```
AUI().use('aui-base','aui-io-request', function(A){
    A.one('#<portlet:namespace/>hospitalName',
        '#<portlet:namespace/>date').on('blur',
        function(){

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select multiple elements by `id` in AlloyUI (and YUI), use the [`Node.all`](http://alloyui.com/api/classes/A.Node.html#method_all) method and [a CSS selector like `#id1, #id2, #id3`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902305/how-to-access-two-ids-in-one-css-selector#9902345).

For your example, the solution would look something like this:

```
A.all('#<portlet:namespace/>hospitalName, #<portlet:namespace/>date').on('blur',
    function(event){
        // event.target is the blurred element.
        /* your code here... */
    }
);
```

See this runnable example for more details:

```js
YUI().use('node', function(A) {

  A.all('#hospitalName, #date').on('blur', function(event) {
    var input = event.target;
    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = input.get('id') + ' blurred';
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/stiemannkj1/0214fdc4cccaa77d6e504320cf70a571/raw/63d260364730fb067f103c00862c7e65685256df/yui-3.18.1_build_yui_yui-min.js"></script>
Hospital Name:
<input type="text" id='hospitalName' />
Date:
<input type="text" id='date' />
<div id="output"></div>
```